# Spring can't see application.properties inside a docker container

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot

I am trying to run a spring-boot application inside docker, my application has several properties stored in its application.properties shipped with the jar. It runs smoothly on just java (java -jar appname.jar)

After dockerizing the application however spring cant see the application.properties file correctly

For those interested here is my dockerfile

```
FROM java:7
EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME /tmp
ADD appname.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

When I try to run it I get

```
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'auth.login.key' in string value "${auth.login.key}"
```

Do I need to mount the application.properties separately? This seems a bit dirty since the properties file makes sense to be shipped with the jar rather than live on the host filesystem.
Maybe fiddle around with the settings for spring-boot? (I am using all default settings)

Comment: For others having the same problem as this I managed to make it work by creating a src/main/resources folder in my project and putting the application.properties there. Really strange behavior for people not familiar with how docker and spring-boot jars interact (like me)

Comment: If the question is answered, could you please mark as answered ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like your comment, moving the application.properties file to src/main/resources folder (as it always should have been) solves the problem.